# trying to upload file - You have an error in your SQL syntax,

Tags: php, mysqli, upload, localhost, mariadb

I'm receiving an error when I try to upload image file to my database for post. Image appears in my folder but won't add it to mysql database.
I am still a beginner, don't judge... and I cannot find a mistake...
error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = 'myusername'' at line 1

here's code:

```
  $Destination = 'userfiles/posts';
    if(!isset($_FILES['attachment_image']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment_image']['tmp_name'])){
        $attachnewimg= 'default-background.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment_image']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$attachnewimg");
    }
    else{
        $RandomNum = rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        $ImageName = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['attachment_image']['name']));
        $ImageType = $_FILES['attachment_image']['type'];
        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
        $attachnewimg = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment_image']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$attachnewimg");
    }
    $sql1="UPDATE users SET attachment_image='$attachnewimg' WHERE username = '$temp'";
    $sql2="INSERT INTO users (attachment_image) VALUES ('$attachnewimg') WHERE username = '$temp'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$temp'");
    if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['attachment_image']['name'])){
            mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            header("location:/");
        }
    } 
    else {
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        header("location:/");
    }
```

Comment: INSERT statements don't have WHERE clauses (unless INSERT SELECT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **INSERT** query is incorrect there is no **where** condition in insert query. Change your insert query like below:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO users (username ,attachment_image) VALUES ('$temp','$attachnewimg')";
```

Check syntax for INSERT statement:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: now it uploads the image to every previous post but not the one i just added. and it changes the image to all previous posts to the same..

here is screenshot https://prnt.sc/j0oo8o

Comment: Then check for `if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {` this condition what it returns?

Comment: I have mistaken, I need to get the ID from the table, i changed the code a little bit - changed the **username = '$temp'** to **WHERE id = '.$id.'** and now it creates 2 tables every time I submit the article.  here is screenshot - https://prnt.sc/j0otq9 , how do I prevent it from creating 2 tables but put all information in one?

Comment: thank you, after changing some more things, everything works now.